# Flutter access QR code sensor (POS machine)

Tags: android, flutter, pos

[image: Text]
Before buying this android machine I want to know that can I access the QR code reader which is a sensor not a camera using flutter?
same thing for the thermal printer and the NFC reader can flutter access and use them?
and is there any packages i can use.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this plugin to use NFC https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_manager or https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nfc_kit